# How to not replace named parameters in EntityManager.createNativeQuery()?

Tags: java, jboss, oracle11g, hibernate-entitymanager

I am using JBOSS AS 7 and I have to use this command prior to querying:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT =\"YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS\"");
```

Now if I fire up this query the error message "Not all named parameters have been set: [MI:SS]" is shown. That makes sense, and I understand named parameters and everything. But just in this case I want this whole string not fiddled with.

I also tried to set the "parameter"  "MI" to MI and "SS" to SS, but that did not help either.

How can I fire this query up without Hibernate trying to replace the named parameters?
Or how can I set this information globally in the application server resp. in the persistence.xml or the standalone.xml from JBOSS?

Comment: try to use double colon `'::'` in place of single colon `':'`

`HH24::MI::SS`

Answer (score 0):

Try with single quotes:

```
String sql = "alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'";
entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping like this:

```
"alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'"
```